# Order of topological phase transitions

Tags: phase-transition, topological-phase, mean-field-theory

I heard in a talk that topological phase transitions are generally higher order than two, and are described by non-local order parameters.

1. Is there an argument why the order is greater than 2?
2. Is there a mean field theory description of topological phase transitions in general, such that the non-local order parameter takes different values in different phases, and consequently the $r$th derivative of the free energy diverges, where $r$ is the order of the phase transition.

Also please suggest some references which contain examples of mean field theory of topological phase transitions with order greater than 2.